# Next.js 'Cannot find module './filename.jpeg'. Not enough time to upload the image

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, fs, sharp

Trying to solve this problem at least half of week. I'm trying to create the playlist page.

First of all I get the information about playlists with **getServerSideProps** and send it to the state. Then I will change this state until user leaves the page. State is the object array, where object is info about playlists. Every object is sent to the special playlist component via props.

If user wants to create new playlists, he opens the modal window and sets the information (name and description) and chooses own picture for it (or user can leave the default picture). After submitting this information will be sent to the database and the picture will be fixed via sharp.js, then will be saved as the file on the server via multer. Then modal window will be closed and user should see the updated playlist list.

Playlist component includes the next/image component. In src I get the image via `(requrie(.../${avatar})`. After first render or creating the new playlist with default picture my construction works perfect. **But if user uploads his own picture, then (after submitting) page instantly breaks and the error "cannot find module ./filename.jpeg" appears, then in 2-3 seconds error disappears and user has only white screen (untill the full reload).**

**Page Playlists.tsx**

```
  const Playlists: React.FC<PlaylistsProps> = ({ user, playlists }) => {
  const [playlistList, setPlaylistList] = React.useState(playlists);
  const [isModalActive, setIsModalActive] = React.useState(false);
  const handleAddPlaylistClick = () => {
    setIsModalActive(true);
  };

  const handleUploadedClick = () => {
    alert("Uploaded playlist");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={clsx({
          [styles.mask]: isModalActive,
        })}
      />
      <PlaylistModal
        active={isModalActive}
        modalClose={setIsModalActive}
        setPlaylistList={setPlaylistList}
      />
      <main className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.main}>
          <Header name={user.userName!} avatar={user.avatarUrl!} />
          <Aside />
          <div className={styles.title}>
            <div className={styles.picture}>
              <Image
                src="/logo/logo-love-1000.png"
                width={150}
                height={150}
                alt="logo"
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.text}>
              <span>Playlists</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <section className={styles.playlists_wrapper}>
            <ul className={styles.playlists}>
              <li
                onClick={handleAddPlaylistClick}
                className={clsx(styles.playlist, styles.compulsory)}
              >
                <svg
                  viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                  className={clsx(styles.avatar, styles.svg)}
                >
                  <path d="m256 512c-141.164062 0-256-114.835938-256-256s114.835938-256 256-256 256 114.835938 256 256-114.835938 256-256 256zm0-480c-123.519531 0-224 100.480469-224 224s100.480469 224 224 224 224-100.480469 224-224-100.480469-224-224-224zm0 0" />
                  <path d="m368 272h-224c-8.832031 0-16-7.167969-16-16s7.167969-16 16-16h224c8.832031 0 16 7.167969 16 16s-7.167969 16-16 16zm0 0" />
                  <path d="m256 384c-8.832031 0-16-7.167969-16-16v-224c0-8.832031 7.167969-16 16-16s16 7.167969 16 16v224c0 8.832031-7.167969 16-16 16zm0 0" />
                </svg>
                <span className={styles.name}>Add new playlist</span>
              </li>
              <li
                onClick={handleUploadedClick}
                className={clsx(styles.playlist, styles.compulsory)}
              >
                <svg
                  className={clsx(styles.svg, styles.avatar)}
                  version="1.1"
                  viewBox="0 0 490.667 490.667"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M245.333,0C110.059,0,0,110.059,0,245.333s110.059,245.333,245.333,245.333s245.333-110.059,245.333-245.333
S380.608,0,245.333,0z M245.333,469.333c-123.52,0-224-100.48-224-224s100.48-224,224-224s224,100.48,224,224
S368.853,469.333,245.333,469.333z"
                  />

                  <path
                    d="M245.333,106.667c-5.888,0-10.667,4.779-10.667,10.667v256c0,5.888,4.779,10.667,10.667,10.667S256,379.221,256,373.333
v-256C256,111.445,251.221,106.667,245.333,106.667z"
                  />

                  <path
                    d="M338.219,195.115l-85.333-85.333c-4.16-4.16-10.923-4.16-15.083,0l-85.333,85.333c-4.16,4.16-4.16,10.923,0,15.083
c4.16,4.16,10.923,4.16,15.083,0l77.781-77.781l77.781,77.803c2.091,2.069,4.821,3.115,7.552,3.115
c2.731,0,5.461-1.045,7.552-3.136C342.379,206.037,342.379,199.275,338.219,195.115z"
                  />
                </svg>

                <span className={styles.name}>Uploaded songs</span>
              </li>
              {playlistList.map((obj, id: number) => (
                <Playlist key={id} name={obj.name} avatar={obj.avatarUrl} />
              ))}
            </ul>
          </section>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  try {
    const user = await checkAuth(ctx);

    if (!user) {
      return {
        props: {},
        redirect: {
          permanent: false,
          destination: "/auth/login",
        },
      };
    }
    if (user.genrePreferences?.length == 0) {
      return {
        props: {},
        redirect: {
          permanent: false,
          destination: "/welcome",
        },
      };
    }
    const playlists = await Api(ctx).getPlaylists();

    return {
      props: {
        playlists,
        user,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
  }
};
```

**PlaylistModal.tsx (modal window)**

```
const PlaylistModal: React.FC<PlaylistModalProps> = ({
  active,
  modalClose,
  setPlaylistList,
}) => {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [imageFile, setImageFile] = React.useState<File>();
  const [playlistInfo, setPlayListInfo] = React.useState<PlaylistInfo>({
    name: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const sendInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      if (imageFile) {
        formData.append("avatar", imageFile);
      } else {
        formData.append("avatar", "");
      }
      formData.append("name", playlistInfo.name);
      formData.append("description", playlistInfo.description);
      const result = await Api().createPlaylist(formData);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleInfoChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent) => {
    setPlayListInfo({
      ...playlistInfo,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const handleImageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.files) {
      const file = target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        setImageUrl(imageUrl);
        setImageFile(file);
        target.value = "";
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSubmitClick = async () => {
    try {
      const newPlaylist = await sendInfo();
      setPlayListInfo({
        name: "",
        description: "",
      });
      setImageFile(undefined);
      setImageUrl("");

      modalClose(false);
      setPlaylistList((prevState) => [...prevState, newPlaylist]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(styles.modal_wrapper, {
        [styles.modal_active]: active,
      })}
    >
      <div className={styles.modal}>
        <svg
          onClick={() => modalClose(false)}
          className={styles.close}
          width="30pt"
          height="30pt"
          viewBox="0 0 511.995 511.995"
        >
          <path
            d="M437.126,74.939c-99.826-99.826-262.307-99.826-362.133,0C26.637,123.314,0,187.617,0,256.005
            s26.637,132.691,74.993,181.047c49.923,49.923,115.495,74.874,181.066,74.874s131.144-24.951,181.066-74.874
            C536.951,337.226,536.951,174.784,437.126,74.939z M409.08,409.006c-84.375,84.375-221.667,84.375-306.042,0
            c-40.858-40.858-63.37-95.204-63.37-153.001s22.512-112.143,63.37-153.021c84.375-84.375,221.667-84.355,306.042,0
            C493.435,187.359,493.435,324.651,409.08,409.006z"
          />

          <path
            d="M341.525,310.827l-56.151-56.071l56.151-56.071c7.735-7.735,7.735-20.29,0.02-28.046
            c-7.755-7.775-20.31-7.755-28.065-0.02l-56.19,56.111l-56.19-56.111c-7.755-7.735-20.31-7.755-28.065,0.02
            c-7.735,7.755-7.735,20.31,0.02,28.046l56.151,56.071l-56.151,56.071c-7.755,7.735-7.755,20.29-0.02,28.046
            c3.868,3.887,8.965,5.811,14.043,5.811s10.155-1.944,14.023-5.792l56.19-56.111l56.19,56.111
            c3.868,3.868,8.945,5.792,14.023,5.792c5.078,0,10.175-1.944,14.043-5.811C349.28,331.117,349.28,318.562,341.525,310.827z"
          />
        </svg>
        <div className={styles.title}>
          <img
            src="/logo/logo-happy-1000.png"
            className={styles.pic}
            alt="logo"
          />
          <span className={styles.text}>Create the playlist</span>
        </div>
        <form className={styles.form}>
          <div className={styles.info}>
            <label htmlFor="upload" className={styles.avatar}>
              <div className={styles.picture}>
                <img
                  width={300}
                  height={300}
                  className={styles.image}
                  src={
                    imageUrl != ""
                      ? imageUrl
                      : "/defaults/playlist-default.jpeg"
                  }
                  alt="avatar"
                />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.text}>
                <span> Choose the avatar</span>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={handleImageChange}
              id="upload"
              className={styles.upload}
              type="file"
              name="avatar"
            />
            <div className={styles.input_info}>
              <div className={styles.input_block}>
                <span className={styles.input_title}>
                  Enter the name of your new playlist:
                </span>
                <input
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name..."
                  className={clsx(styles.input, styles.input_name)}
                  type="text"
                  value={playlistInfo.name}
                  onChange={handleInfoChange}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.input_block}>
                <span className={styles.input_title}>
                  Enter the description of your new playlist:
                </span>
                <textarea
                  name="description"
                  value={playlistInfo.description}
                  placeholder="Description..."
                  className={clsx(styles.input, styles.descr)}
                  onChange={handleInfoChange}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button
            onClick={handleSubmitClick}
            color={["white", "#a406cb", "none"]}
            size={[200, 50]}
            className={styles.submit}
          >
            Lets go
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlaylistModal;
```

**Component Playlist.tsx**

```
const Playlist: React.FC<PlaylistProps> = ({ name, avatar }) => {
  const handlePlaylistClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "svg" && e.target.tagName !== "path") {
      alert(`Playlist named '${name}'`);
    }
  };
  const handleEditClick = () => {
    alert(`Edit '${name}'`);
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<SVGSVGElement>) => {
    alert(`Delete '${name}'`);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={handlePlaylistClick} className={styles.playlist}>
      <Image
        className={styles.avatar}
        width={50}
        height={50}
        src={require(`/server/avatars/playlists/${avatar}`)}
        alt="playlist-avatar"
      />
      <span className={styles.name}>{name}</span>
      <div className={styles.tools}>
        <svg
          onClick={handleEditClick}
          width="30pt"
          height="30pt"
          className={styles.tool}
          viewBox="-15 -15 484.00019 484"
        >
          <path d="m401.648438 18.234375c-24.394532-24.351563-63.898438-24.351563-88.292969 0l-22.101563 22.222656-235.269531 235.144531-.5.503907c-.121094.121093-.121094.25-.25.25-.25.375-.625.746093-.871094 1.121093 0 .125-.128906.125-.128906.25-.25.375-.371094.625-.625 1-.121094.125-.121094.246094-.246094.375-.125.375-.25.625-.378906 1 0 .121094-.121094.121094-.121094.25l-52.199219 156.96875c-1.53125 4.46875-.367187 9.417969 2.996094 12.734376 2.363282 2.332031 5.550782 3.636718 8.867188 3.625 1.355468-.023438 2.699218-.234376 3.996094-.625l156.847656-52.324219c.121094 0 .121094 0 .25-.121094.394531-.117187.773437-.285156 1.121094-.503906.097656-.011719.183593-.054688.253906-.121094.371094-.25.871094-.503906 1.246094-.753906.371093-.246094.75-.621094 1.125-.871094.125-.128906.246093-.128906.246093-.25.128907-.125.378907-.246094.503907-.5l257.371093-257.371094c24.351563-24.394531 24.351563-63.898437 0-88.289062zm-232.273438 353.148437-86.914062-86.910156 217.535156-217.535156 86.914062 86.910156zm-99.15625-63.808593 75.929688 75.925781-114.015626 37.960938zm347.664062-184.820313-13.238281 13.363282-86.917969-86.917969 13.367188-13.359375c14.621094-14.609375 38.320312-14.609375 52.945312 0l33.964844 33.964844c14.511719 14.6875 14.457032 38.332031-.121094 52.949218zm0 0" />
        </svg>
        <svg
          onClick={handleDeleteClick}
          width="30pt"
          height="30pt"
          className={styles.tool}
          viewBox="-40 0 427 427.00131"
        >
          <path d="m232.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
          <path d="m114.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
          <path d="m28.398438 127.121094v246.378906c0 14.5625 5.339843 28.238281 14.667968 38.050781 9.285156 9.839844 22.207032 15.425781 35.730469 15.449219h189.203125c13.527344-.023438 26.449219-5.609375 35.730469-15.449219 9.328125-9.8125 14.667969-23.488281 14.667969-38.050781v-246.378906c18.542968-4.921875 30.558593-22.835938 28.078124-41.863282-2.484374-19.023437-18.691406-33.253906-37.878906-33.257812h-51.199218v-12.5c.058593-10.511719-4.097657-20.605469-11.539063-28.03125-7.441406-7.421875-17.550781-11.5546875-28.0625-11.46875h-88.796875c-10.511719-.0859375-20.621094 4.046875-28.0625 11.46875-7.441406 7.425781-11.597656 17.519531-11.539062 28.03125v12.5h-51.199219c-19.1875.003906-35.394531 14.234375-37.878907 33.257812-2.480468 19.027344 9.535157 36.941407 28.078126 41.863282zm239.601562 279.878906h-189.203125c-17.097656 0-30.398437-14.6875-30.398437-33.5v-245.5h250v245.5c0 18.8125-13.300782 33.5-30.398438 33.5zm-158.601562-367.5c-.066407-5.207031 1.980468-10.21875 5.675781-13.894531 3.691406-3.675781 8.714843-5.695313 13.925781-5.605469h88.796875c5.210937-.089844 10.234375 1.929688 13.925781 5.605469 3.695313 3.671875 5.742188 8.6875 5.675782 13.894531v12.5h-128zm-71.199219 32.5h270.398437c9.941406 0 18 8.058594 18 18s-8.058594 18-18 18h-270.398437c-9.941407 0-18-8.058594-18-18s8.058593-18 18-18zm0 0" />
          <path d="m173.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Playlist;
```

**Request to the server**

```
createPlaylist: async(_info: FormData) => {
            try {
                const { data } = await instance.post("/playlists/create", _info, {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                      }
                    } 
                );
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }      
        },
```

**Handling info and sending to db**

```
async createPlaylist(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        if (req.file) {
            try {
                const { id } = req.user!.data;
                const { filename: image } = req.file 
                const filePath = req.file?.path;
                let newFileName: string;
                newFileName = image;
                await sharp(path.resolve(filePath)).resize(150, 150).toFormat('jpeg').toFile(path.resolve(req.file?.destination, "playlists", newFileName)),  (err: any) => {
                    if (err) {
                      throw err;
                    }
                }

                fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
                const obj = {
                    name: req.body.name,
                    description: req.body.description,
                    avatarUrl: newFileName,
                    songs: [],
                    private: false,
                    belongsTo: id,
                }
                const playlistInfo = await Playlist.create(obj);
                res.status(200).json(playlistInfo);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }

        } else {
            try {
                const { id } = req.user!.data;
                const obj = {
                    name: req.body.name,
                    description: req.body.description,
                    avatarUrl: "default.jpeg",
                    songs: [],
                    private: false,
                    belongsTo: id,
                };
                const playlistInfo = await Playlist.create(obj);
                res.status(200).json(await playlistInfo.toJSON())

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I suppose, this error appears because the user's picture has not enough time to upload on the server folder, so the next/image component actually requires non-existent picture. **How can I await the upload of image on the server and only then update the page? And if this it not the problem, then what can it be?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it, by replacing all avatars from "/server/avatars/playlists" folder to "public/avatars/playlists" folder and changing src in Playlist component

```
<Image
  className={styles.avatar}
  width={50}
  height={50}
  src={`/avatars/playlists/${avatar}`}
  alt="playlist-avatar"
/>
```